# Can't execute script (.sh) with ProcessBuilder and print error in my vps

Tags: java, bash, shell, vps, processbuilder

I'm trying to do a function in Java for execute an .sh script (shutdown) in a linux vps.

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "mkdir", "test"); //here I want to change "mkdir" and "test" by shutdown.sh
                    pb.directory(new File("/opt/tomcat/transfert/"));
                    Process p = pb.start();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        lines.add(line);
                        lines.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("lines", lines);
```

I work on a windows 10 and I pass by a tomcat server on my vps so I can't see any console during execution on the vps (it's for that I pass lines in my request to display this in my webcontent). **If you know how can I print error on the vps output it will be cool**.

But at the execution, nothing is done, there is no change in my "transfert" folder and nothing is return to my web page.

In my debian vps, I updated the differents files and folders permission to be executable and readable.

I saw in an other topic the problem can be the "user" used by the ProcessBuilder haven't the right permission but how to change that ?

So I don't understand why this happend because I change everything in my code and search about many way to run correctly and that don't want to work...

*Written after* : If I try the command directly in my vps console, that works !

**Update** :

I also try to do it like this :

```java
String[] cmd = {
          "/bin/sh",
          "-c",
          "mkdir /home/debian/test"
};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But that don't work more...

Thx, Etienne

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `/bin/bash mkdir test` probably does not work on your system if called directly. You need "-c" to make bash launch another command:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir test");
```

It is safer to use absolute path and scan the error message too, this is easiest by merging error -> stdout and there should be no need to use "/bin/bash" directly if `shutdown.sh` starts with "#!/bin/sh" :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/tomcat/transfert/shutdown.sh");
 // merge STDERR to STDOUT - or call redirectError(File)
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Comment: Hello @DuncG, thx for your answer ! I change my code with ```ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir test");``` and that don't work... But thanks a lot for the redirectError method, I try this now and I tell you back if I can see the errors !

Comment: I found how to solve this with the logs, I have an local export problem and now it works with `ProcessBuilder("/opt/tomcat/transfert/shutdown.sh")` ! Thx. I allow myself to ask an other question : I want to make the same but with java execution... This is my local environment : `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-16.0.2` `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` so I try to do my request like this : `/opt/jdk-16.0.2/bin", "-c", "java /home/debian/Client ipAdress id password` (this programm is in javaSocket and send id and password to the ipAdress. But that doesn't works : " error=13, Permission denied"